# Swift 4 WebkitView URL change not doing its job

Tags: swift, ios11, ios12

I am having the following situation.

I am using a WebkitView to display some session information. In most places it's generated when the ViewController comes to life, but I have one particular view in which I have to reload it on user interactions with buttons that change to next or previous month.

I have the following code:

```
// This is my connection to the storyboard element
@IBOutlet weak var areaNotasMes: WKWebView!
```

After that I have a function that does the URL handling:

```
func actualizarUrlNotasMes(fechaNueva: Date) {
    let formateadorAdicional = DateFormatter()
    formateadorAdicional.dateFormat = "yyyyMM"

    let url = URL(string: "https://myurl/\(formateadorAdicional.string(from: fechaNueva))")

    areaNotasMes.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
}
```

And I have a button event that uses the function with the next YEAR_MONTH combination like this:

```
@IBAction func mesSigPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Some more code to get the fechaActual variable
    actualizarUrlNotasMes(fechaNueva: fechaActual)
    // Some more code
}
```

So, basically what's happening is that it loads the first time I open the ViewController, but when I click on the button to change to the next month, the date gets changed, correctly generated and passed to the function. It generates the correct URL, but when the `areaNotasMes.load(...)` function runs, nothing refreshes on the WebKitView. I tried adding `areaNotasMes.reload()`, but it also did nothing. Do I have to like destroy and recreate the WebKitView each time I change the URL? Or am I not handling the URL change correctly?

Also, the console pops up some of these messages from time to time, not always:

```
[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C5.1:2][0x7fea2d201de0] get output frames failed, state 8196
TIC Read Status [5:0x0]: 1:57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I actually managed to fix this in the most random way. I thought maybe there's some reload function (except for `.reload()`) so using the auto completion of syntax, I came up with the following command:

`areaNotasMes.reloadInputViews()`

Apparently `.reloadInputViews()` is a void function inherited from `UIView` which updates the custom input and accessory views when the object is the first responder. You can check it here: [reloadInputViews()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621110-reloadinputviews)

It does send some `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)"` although it actually works as supposed and refreshes the WebKitView information.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to re-initialize the webview when changing the URL. I can't tell the issue with the information you provided. I would advise that you set the ViewController as `navigationDelegate` of the webview and implement these method to try to diagnose the issue :

```
func webView(WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!)

func webView(WKWebView, didFail: WKNavigation!, withError: Error)
//Called when an error occurs during navigation.

 func webView(WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!, withError: Error)
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)

Comment: To be honest I am relatively new to Swift, how should I approach this, implement protocol or extend the view controller with navigationDelegate or point the controller to the WebKitView. I am not sure how to go about what you recommend Wassim.

Comment: yes exactly. let your ViewController conform to the WKNavigationDelegate, then set then navigationDelegate of the webview to self.

Comment: Ok, I did the following:

`class ElMesController: BaseController, WKNavigationDelegate` then I did this 

`override func viewDidLoad() { ... areaNotasMes.navigationDelegate = self ... }` and inside my controller I added the 3 functions you mentioned. Inside `didStartProvisionalNavitagion` I added a `print("yes")` and inside the error ones I added `print(error)` 

Everytime I change to the next month I get a yes in console and nothing more. And like 10-20 seconds later I get the Boring SSL and TIC messages. Nothing else happens.